# Pass arguments to a CURL GET call

Tags: unix, curl, parameters

I am trying to execute a CURL call by passing parameters.

However, it does not return the intended output.

Here is the code:

```
curl -X GET 'http://admin-app.prod.order-services.cp.glb.prod.walmart.com/order-services-admin/plutus-admin/published-transactions/count?fromDate=$from_date&toDate=$to_date'
```

Please let me know how I can pass $from_date and $to_date in the above URL.

Comment: When you try this, what does the output look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to substitute the values of variables `$from_date` and `$to_date` in the link. Variables are not substituted in [single quoted strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html#Single-Quotes). Try replacing single quotes with [double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html#Double-Quotes):

```
curl -X GET "http://admin-app.prod.order-services.cp.glb.prod.walmart.com/order-services-admin/plutus-admin/published-transactions/count?fromDate=$from_date&toDate=$to_date"
```